# How can I authenticate to my applications webservice after using Facebook SSO on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am creating an Android app that uses Facebook SSO to login and I'm not sure how to authenticate with my own webservices after I login to FB.  When a user first opens my app they login to Facebook, authorize my application some privileges, and continue into my app.  This part works great, but now to use my app they need to create an account on my server and talk to my webservices.

Right now I have a call to an authenticate webservice on my server that adds their Facebook ID and other basic info into a database and at the same time does a Diffie–Hellman key exchange so any future calls to webservices can be encrypted by a shared key.  But the problem is that very first initial call to create this account and create this shared key, how do I authenticate that?  How do I know this person is really the one who just authenticated with Facebook and not just someone who found the URL for my webservice and is creating accounts and saving the keys?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Facebook SSO returns an access token. If you'd like, you can pass that along to your server and your server can make a call to the Facebook APIs to check that it's a valid access token for that user (eg by calling  https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN) -- if it is, you're good and have verified that the user is who they say they are (or is a hacker with enough access to have a valid auth token for your app for Facebook, at which point their identity has been compromised on Facebook's end).

Comment: That access token is sensitive, so I assume I would have to use SSL on my webservice calls when I pass it back to my server?

Comment: I would. Since Facebook doesn't do the secret-key signing stuff anymore, someone could fake requests from your app using just the token.

Comment: (If you were using OAuth instead of SSO, you could request an OAuth 2.0 one-use code that you could redeem for an auth token server side, but SSO doesn't offer that option (neither does the Facebook SDK without modification of the URLs it calls)).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use the access token to verify the user is who they said they were and make my webservice calls SSL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to pass a password along with your basic info upon profile creation. All in all, the Facebook SSO only gives your client application the right to access the profile user, but it does not garantee your web services that the caller is the actual owner of this FB account. I am afraid that subsequent calls from the Android client to the web service needs to be authenticated via a normal user/name password ( different from the FB account ) if you want to be sure that the caller is the one who retrieved the key the first time ( no matter what Facebook profile he might be linked to ).

Comment: Ya, that is what I'm starting to suspect.  But Facebook touts one of the main advantages of using their SSO is it gets rid of a need for user registration (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login).

I can see how this would work using a web client and using a redirect-uri, but on Android Facebook SDK I don't think this happens the same way.  What would be ideal is if Facebook returned the session key to the phone AND to some redirect-uri at the same time

Comment: Yes, but the only thing it returns is the user profile, with the unique FB id but this is not enough to authenticate the second leg towards the application backend server.

Comment: It actually returns a session key that the phone can then use to make Facebook API calls.  What would be ideal is if Facebook sent that session key to the phone and to some service on my website at the same time, effectively creating the shared session for me.  I just hate the idea of making a user create a password for my site if they have already logged into FB.  It goes against the whole idea of using Facebook's SSO, I feel like I'm missing something.