# Verification of user on 3rd party server using google account

Tags: android, web-services

I have an android application and for authentication I am using one of the existing accounts on Android and generating an authToken from it.

Now, I have a server where I need to authenticate this user to call some server specific API's from the Android application. I don't want to create a separate username/password for the same user to access those API's.

I would prefer something like, I pass the authToken generated from the Android app to the server and then it validates this token. Then I will be able to authenticate the user and generate a session for him to access the server API's

Please let me know how this can be achieved?

Thanks in Advance

Cheers,
Prateek

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing and came across another similar question.  Unfortunately it only raises more questions/cautions. 

[How can I authenticate to my applications webservice after using Facebook SSO on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109754/how-can-i-authenticate-to-my-applications-webservice-after-using-facebook-sso-on/5110283#5110283)